# PHP.INI settings not working on Debian 10 PHP Version 8.0

Tags: debian, apache2, php-8

I can't get my PHP settings working using Apache2, PHP 8.0 on Debian 10 Linux. I have tried updating all the php.ini files in /etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini, /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini & /etc/php/8.0/fpm/php.ini. I have searched my entire filesystem and there are no other php.ini files to be found.

I have also tried setting the php_value in my .htaccess file on Apache2 without success. I have even added the ini_set(variable, value) in my php script and the directly afterwards did a print ini_get(variable) and it works when I run it from a command line, but from my browser, the value is still incorrect. I always restart apache after making any changes and clear my cache, but nothing seems to work. I am pretty sure this was working correctly using the same OS with the previous PHP 7.3 version.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, I found the answer. I needed to disable the php7.3 mod and enable the php8.0 mod in Apache2, then restart the service.

i.e. a2dismod php7.3 && a2enmod php8.0 && systemctl restart apache2.service